# How to create double nested model with a twist in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, mass-assignment, rails-models

I'm creating a registration where I have "Person" "Child" and "Meal" Models. Person can have many Children and can register many Meals for themselves but also many Meals for Children.

The point is that the Meals belong to only the Person (no point to assign them to the Children) so I have one creation part for meals in the form and also another creation under the children.

When I submit the form I get the *Can't mass-assign protected attributes: meals* error in the Person's controller.

Question is, how can I create Meals instances under the Children fields_for section without getting this error and without building connection between Meals and Children?

Here is my Person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :meals
has_many :registrations, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :programs, :through => :registrations
has_many :children

attr_accessible :email_address, :first_name, :home_country, :payment, :phone_number,   :price_category, :price_method, :reference_number, :second_name, :meals_attributes, :registrations_attributes, :children_attributes

validate :first_name, :second_name, :home_country, :email_address, :payment, :price_method, :presence => true

accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['meal_type'].blank? }
accepts_nested_attributes_for :registrations, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
```

My Meal model

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :food_type, :meal_date, :meal_type, :person_id, :meal_id

 validate :food_type, :meal_date, :meal_type, :presence => true

 belongs_to :person

end
```

The new part of my Person controller

```
def new
 @person = Person.new
 meal = @person.meals.build
 @meal_dates = ["2013-07-09","2013-07-10","2013-07-11","2013-07-12","2013-07-13","2013-07-14"]
 registration = @person.registrations.build
 child = @person.children.build
 @programs = Program.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @person }
end
```

This is the children part in the main _form

```
<h2>Children</h2>
 <%= f.fields_for :children do |builder| %>
  <%= render "child_fields", :f => builder %>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to_add_fields 'Add Children', f, :children %>
```

And the child fields with the meals

```
 <fieldset>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :age %><br />
   <%= f.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :language %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :language %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :child_care %><br />
   <%= f.check_box :child_care %>
  </div>
  <h3>Child's meals</h3>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Food type</th>
  <th>Meal type</th>
  </tr>
  <% @meal_dates.each do |meal_date| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :meals do |f3| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= f3.text_field :meal_date, :value => meal_date %></td>
    <td><%= f3.hidden_field :food_type, :class => 'FoodType', :value => 'vegetarian'%></td>
    <td><%= f3.select(:meal_type, [['Lunch', 1], ['Three Meals', 3], ['None', nil]]) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </table>

  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
  </fieldset>
```

You can find the full code in my github: https://github.com/szabcsee/brk2013

Comment: Why are the meals not assigned to the children?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit confuse in modelling IMO.

The Meal model, different from common sense, is actually a kind of order in your case. With this in mind I can understand the logic basically.

To solve your problem I suggest to add a field in the Meal(order) model. The field is to store who will eat this meal. The name can be `for_whom`, `eater` or whatever understandable.

The default value of this field is 0, which means this meal is for this person himself.(Why not this person's id? Because you need to search children's id using this field. The person's id is already stored in the orderer)

When a person order the meal, he'll see an option(Radios or Select), asking him who the meal is for. The option will populated with ids or his children, and himself(as 0).

When handling the form, if the option value is bigger than 0, that will mean a child's id. Then you can handle it accordingly.

To show a child's meal, just query the meal table with the child's id.

Comment: Actually the problem is not that who will eat the meal because it's irrelevant from the organisers point of view. Rather that I can not save a Meal model instance if it's under the Child's fields_for section because of the mass assignment error.

Comment: @szabcsee, it's easy to solve mass assignments error, just add this field in attr_accessible in the model. For the modelling, you decide it, I just feel a bit unnature.

Comment: if you check, it's already added there. In the meantime I moved towards polymorphic assignment for child and person.

Comment: @szabcsee, it seems there is no Child model?